# Question about a plural

Tags: grammatical-number

Recently I’ve encountered an exercise that my teacher marked as wrong, but I’m pretty sure it isn’t.

I have to complete with various words some phrases. In this case the words are: *instruction, instruct, instructed, instructor* (note that the context is about computer science).

The phrase is:

> Both … and data have to be changed to machine code.

The exercise specified that I might have to change some words slightly, so I put *instructions*.

The thing that my teacher corrected is the 's'.

Is it acceptable in both forms? Or am I/is she wrong?

Comment: Although the non-count usage is reasonably common, 'instruction' is so unlikely here that I'd mark **_it_** wrong. I'd only allow 'instructions'. // 'Data' is the more difficult noun! Thankfully, it's in an obviously notionally plural coordinate structure here (it's a plural-form noun usually treated as non-count and given singular agreement).

Comment: Welcome! By the way, there's a separate [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange that you might find helpful. (And yes, the short answer is that your teacher is wrong, and also that it's not a great question. Seems like it would have been more useful if it dealt with "instructions" OR "data" separately and asked you to identify them as singular or plural...)

Comment: The computer science usage of _instruction_ in this context -- machine code -- is singular. A location in memory may contain an instruction -- some numeric code with a meaning -- or data -- a numeric code with a different meaning. The trick in computing is for software to distinguish its instructions from its data; it's rather like distinguishing the verb from the object -- both are words, so how do you tell?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions, i will probably talk with my teacher (just to let her know, consider that I'm Italian and she's not a native speaker so..) and the next time I'll try to use the _English Language Learners_ exchange

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on ELL but is too old to migrate.